# AlarmManager triggers every 20seconds instead of using the given interval

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager, alarm

Can someone enlighten me and what am I doing wrong? I want to trigger my alarm every 15minutes.
Here is the sample.

```
alarmManager?.let{
         if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + (15*1000*60), //This line works.
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, //This interval does not work.
                pendingIntent
            )          
         }
     }
```

And this is my database which you will see the interval is 20seconds

[image]

Comment: You can try `exact repeating` instead of `inexact`. By the way, have you called it multiple times?

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I already found out  it was my hierarchy in the code that causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I found out what is the problem here is my broadcast receiver

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent){
    try{
        locationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager?  
        var resend = true;    
        val locationListener: LocationListener = object : LocationListener {
        override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
            val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
            val day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
            val editor = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            editor.putString("Name", "${intent.getStringExtra("Name")}")
            editor.apply()
            //RUN ONLY ON WEEKDAYS
            if(day != 1 || day != 7){
                Log.d("ALARM MANAGER","RINGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGER")
                Log.d("EXTRA","${intent.getStringExtra("Name")}")
                Log.d("LATITUDE","${location.latitude}")
                Log.d("LONGITUDE","${location.longitude}")
                if(resend){
                    sendRequest(location.latitude, location.longitude, "${intent.getStringExtra("Name")}", context);  
                }
                resend = false
            }       
        }
        override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String, status: Int, extras: Bundle) {}
        override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String) {}
        override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String) {}
     }
        locationManager?.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000L, 0f, locationListener)
    }
    catch(e: Exception){
        Log.d("Exception","$e")
    }
}
```

I added a boolean so that it wont call my api every "onLocationChanged"